# How to correctly override a persistent input variable on instanciation and call in a derived FUNCTION_BLOCK?

Tags: codesys

I have a input variable `c_timTransmissionRate` which is usually initalized using the persistent variable list. The default value for the persistent variable list in the function block `TxRaw` is then overriden by the instanciating function block ´TxDbc´. This again is application specific overriden in the persistent variable list itself.

In a few cases the value for `c_timTransmissionRate` is provided dynamically by the instanciating function block `TxTsc1` during runtime.

My problem is that I currently always see the original `TIME#0ms` value in the debugger instead of the values given in the persistent variable list.

Extract of my current code:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK TxRaw
 VAR_INPUT PERSISTENT CONSTANT
  c_timTransmissionRate : TIME := T#0ms;
 END_VAR
  (* instructions *)
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK

FUNCTION_BLOCK Tx
VAR
 tx : TxRaw;
END_VAR
  (* instructions *)
 tx();
  (* instructions *)
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK

FUNCTION_BLOCK TxTsc1 EXTENDS Tx
  (* instructions *)
  tx.c_timTransmissionRate := PI()*THUMB();
  SUPER^();
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK

FUNCTION BLOCK TxDbc EXTENDS Tx
VAR
 tx : TX := (c_timTransmissionRate := T#20ms);
END_VAR
  (* instructions *)
  SUPER^();
END_FUNCTION_BLOCK
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use CONSTANT together with VAR_INPUT.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Felix. I assumed that ˋCONSTANTˋ declares the variable as immutable in the POU like for functions in C. Am I wrong there?

Comment: You can use CONSTANT with VAR only. Somehow if it is combined with VAR_INPUT it gets ignored / no error and you can still change your VAR_INPUT CONSTANT variables. If you try to change a VAR CONSTANT variable you get a compiler error. But you can still change VAR CONSTANT variables manually in online view.